# PHP loop through array returned by MySQL function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, loops

The code below works fine. However I would like to output the results using a loop. I can do it by going through each key individually or as $post[0] for example but not using a loop to go through all the returned fields. All I get is one value of "Array". It looks like the entire array is inserted into a variable I'm not sure what's going on. I have tried http://www.hackingwithphp.com/5/3/0/the-two-ways-of-iterating-through-arrays. Any suggestions appreciated and also if anyone could explain what is going on that would be great. Thanks.

```
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];

    function query($ID){
        $servername = "x.x.x.x";
        $username = "xxxxx";
        $password = "xxxxx";
        $dbname = "xxxxx";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $query = "SELECT ID, NAME, POSITION, TELEPHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM GROUP WHERE ID = '$ID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $resArr[] = $row;
        }
        return $resArr;
    }

    $person = query($ID);
    foreach($person as $post) {
    echo $post['ID'] . "<br>";
    echo $post['NAME'] . "<br>";
    echo $post['POSITION'] . "<br>";
    echo $post['TELEPHONE_NUMBER'] . "<br>";
    echo $post['EMAIL'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: group is a reserved word. This cannot be your query. Busted.

Comment: Check for errors. Try `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` Show your entire code looks like you have an extra **}** closing braces after `return $resArr;`

Comment: Uchiha is almost right - the only error checking you've done here is on the mysqli_connect(). Enabling error reporting is good practice for a development machine but you should be explicitly polling for errors more often (particularly on mysqli_query() where you would have seen the problem reported by Strawberry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not totally clear what you are asking but I assume you want to loop through the individual fields of the selected rows. As you built an array containing the query results each result itself being an array `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` then you can just add an inner loop to process the individual row array like so :-

```
$persons = query($ID);
foreach($persons as $person) {
    foreach ( $person as $fieldname => $value ) {
        echo $fieldname . '-' . $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Group` is reserved word of mysql you can use it in backtics ``

```
$query = "SELECT ID, NAME, POSITION, TELEPHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM `GROUP` WHERE ID = '$ID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Its not braces its backtics Mate

Comment: I changed all variables...anyway this works fine I can use it all I want to know is if there is a better way that this can be done like start from field 0 and keep going until field x?

Comment: @John first of all change your MySQL query

Comment: thats what i mean thats not the proper sql query the query works fine everything works